# SpringBoot @OneToMany Trigger Error And Request Sending Error

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, one-to-many

I have 2 entity classes. One employee should has one department. But one department can has many employees.

When I send to postman request insert employee, I want to trigger Department table.

```
@Table
@Entity(name = "employee")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "employee_name", nullable = false)
    private String employeeName;

    @Column(name = "employee_surname", nullable = false)
    private String employeeSurname;

    @Column(name = "employee_email",
            nullable = false,
            unique = true)
    private String employeeEmail;

    @Column(name = "employee_identity_number",
            nullable = false,
            unique = true,
            length = 11)
    private String employeeIdentityNumber;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;


}
```

Above code my Employee class.

```
@Table
@Entity(name = "department")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long departmentId;

    @Column(name = "department_name", unique = true)
    private String departmentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private Set<Employee> employees;

}
```

Above code my Department class.

When I send postman request as JSON like following,

```
{
    "employeeName": "Josh",
    "employeeSurname": "Long",
    "employeeEmail": "joshlong@gmail.com",
    "employeeIdentityNumber": "12345678912",
    "department": 1
}
```

I know, department property is wrong. I should define as department object. But i want to send just department id.

And when I send this request, I want to trigger employees field in department table.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a dto object like this

```
public class EmployeeDto{
    private String employeeName;
    private String employeeSurname;
    private String employeeEmail;
    private String employeeIdentityNumber;
    private long departmentId;
}
```

A controller mthod like this:

```
@PostMapping("employee")
public Employee save(@RequestBody EmployeeDto employeeDto){
    Employee em = employeeDto.toEntity();
    //Assuming department with given id already exist
    em.setDepartment(Department.builder().departmentId(employeeDto.departmentId).build());
    return emRepository.save(employee);
}
```

to my knowlage, this should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
{
   "employeeName": "Josh",
   "employeeSurname": "Long",
   "employeeEmail": "joshlong@gmail.com",
   "employeeIdentityNumber": "12345678912",
   "department": {"departmentId": "5342432432"}
}
```

and for department,

```
{
   "departmentName": "department", 
   "employees" : [{"id" : "79878"}, {"id": "654654"}, ...]
}
```